# Octave/Matlab version of this Python for-loop

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, image-processing, octave

I just want to know if there is any Octave/Matlab equivalent syntax for this particular for-loop in python:

```
for (i,j) in [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7)]:
    a[i,j] = 1
```

I need it to ease out my Image processing assignments where I can easily construct Image matrix without having to enter each pixel value for almost each element of the Image matrix. So, if there are any other ways of implementing the above functionality in Octave/Matlab, then please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Octave ,I guess also in MATLAB, you can do:

```
for ij = [{1;2} {2;3} {3;4} {4;5} {5;6} {6;7}]
    a(ij{:}) = 1;
end
```

But in general In MATLAB and Python it is better to prevent loops. There are much efficient indexing methods both in [Python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/user/basics.indexing.html) and [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a series of pixels in `a`, given by coordinates, to the same value, you can do as follows:

```matlab
coord = [1,2; 2,3; 3,4; 4,5; 5,6; 6,7];
ind = sub2ind(size(a), coord(:,1), coord(: 2));
a(ind) = 1;
```

You can replace that last `1` with a vector with as many elements as coordinates in `coord` to assign a different value to each pixel.

Note that MATLAB indexes rows with the first index, so the first column of `coord` corresponds to the y coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest here would be:

```
for i = 1 : 6
   a(i, i+1) = 1; % Alternatively: j=i+1; a(i,j)=1;
end
```

The more flexible alternative is to construct the pairs:

```
vals = [1,2; … ; 6,7]; % Your i,j pairs. Possibly even put 3 numbers there, i,j,value.
for i = 1 : size(vals, 1)
   a(vals(i,1), vals(i,2)) = 1;
end
```